# SET VARIABLE FROM A TEXT FILE

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, set

hi I am trying to set a variable read from a text file. I am using a FOR cycle and I can read every line from a text but when I try to use the SET command I can't save it into a variable named: myvar. What am I doing wrong. Any ideas: 
this is my code:

```
@echo off 
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN (c:\users\victor\desktop\v1.txt) DO ( 
echo:%%a >> result.txt 
set myvar=%%a 
echo:%myvar%  
) 
@PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

See any of many, many, many SO entries regarding "delayedexpansion"

Comment: I understand what you mean, so I did this:

    'for /F "delims=^" %%a IN (c:\users\victor\desktop\v1.txt) DO (
    echo:%%a >> result.txt
    set myvar=%%a
    goto :break1 
    )
    :break1
    echo:var %myvar% >> result.txt'

but it is only giving me the first line of the text file and that is it. it is not going thru the rest of the text file.

Comment: `goto` breakes the block. Means: once the script jumped to a label, there is no return. But you can use `call` instead of `goto`.